# Any code templates to draw 3D field lines inline?

Tags: 3d

I'm particularly interested in magnetic and electric field lines such as showed in this picture (from http://www.grasshopper3d.com/forum/topics/creating-a-3d-field):

[image: Magnetic dipole field lines.]

Comment: You may take a look at pst electric field package. Documentation at http://get-software.net/graphics/pstricks/contrib/pst-electricfield/pst-electricfield-docEN.pdf

Comment: @PMC1234 I've used `pst-electrifield` a lot since you suggested it. Thank you! As my question is about drawing 3D lines, `pst-electricfield` doesn't fulfill my expectations despite being very useful. I've just found a dipolar magnetic field example (http://www.texample.net/tikz/examples/dipolar-magnetic-field/). If you are interested, I would accept an answer from you citing both `pst-electricfield` and that code example, as well as additional stuff if you have more to say. If you (or somebody else with more information) are not interested, I'm going to answer my own question.

Comment: I don't particularly enjoy answering my own questions, so I'm going to wait for more answers a little longer before doing so.

Comment: @LeonardoCastro As long as an answer is given, everything is fine.

Answer (score 0):

There is such a template by Cyril Langlois on this page:

[Example: Dipolar magnetic field](https://texample.net/tikz/examples/dipolar-magnetic-field/)